# Function return type mismatch doesn't produce any errors

Tags: function, rust

I'm new to Rust and trying to understand how reference works. Below is a simple function.

```
fn f1(x: &i32) -> &i32{
    x
}
```

Since `x` is of type `&i32`, return it directly matches the return type `&i32`. But I found that if I change the function to this, it also compiles without any problem:

```
fn f1(x: &i32) -> &i32{
    &x
}
```

Here `x` is of type `&i32`, `&x` is of type `&&i32` and doesn't match the return type `&i32`. Why it compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of [type coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html).

To make the language more ergonomic, a [certain set of coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) are allowed in specific situations. One of the situations is determining the return value of a function.

Among the allowed coercions is this:

> &T or &mut T to &U if T implements Deref<Target = U>

In this particular case, there is an [implementation of the deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-4) trait in the std library:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> const Deref for &T {
    type Target = T;

    #[rustc_diagnostic_item = "noop_method_deref"]
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        *self
    }
}
```

In your case, the target `T` is `i32`, and the trait is implemented for `&T` (ie. `&i32`) so `deref(&self) -> &T` can coerce from `&&i32` to `&i32`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second function Rust automatically *dereferences* `&x` to `x` (i.e. `&&i32` to `&i32`). That's done via the so called "Deref coercion".

Consider this example:

```
fn f1(x: &i32) -> &i32{
    let t1: &&i32 = &x;     // nothing special here
    let t2: &i32 = &x;      // this works too
    let t3: &i32 = &&&&x;   // this works too!
    let t4: i32 = x;        // this doesn't work though
    x
}
```